# Keras seq2seq model how to mask padding zeros from validation when training?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am working on a project based on this great tutorial. https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-encoder-decoder-model-sequence-sequence-prediction-keras/

I have had to pad the end of my input and output sequences with zeros to keep them the same length, e.g.

[72  1 62  0 68  4 72  0 63  0 68  5 83  3 87  1 86  1 84  3 86 13 74  0
 71  2 87  5 90  3 63  0 66  0 76  2 36  1 38  1 67  0 34  0 61  4 89  4
 62  0 40  0 63  0 31  1 39  5 88  4 68  0 68  0 72  3 71  0 78  3 67  1
 66  0 64  5 63  1 67  2 61  0 61  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]

[77 77  5 76  2 77 78 71  1 79  1 77 76 79 71 71  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]

However this means that during training/validations, the model will get a higher validation result than it should becuase it will easily learn to match the zero elements of the sequences.

I have added the Masking function below to the encoder_inputs & decoder_inputs, but after making the modification I get the error;

```
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, n_in))
encoder_inputs = Masking(mask_value=0)(encoder_inputs) #****** TEST *****

....

decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, n_out))
decoder_inputs = Masking(mask_value=0)(decoder_inputs) #****** TEST *****
```

ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_14:0", shape=(None, None, 80), dtype=float32) at layer "input_14". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: ['input_13']

```
def define_models(n_in, n_out, n_units):
# define encoder
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, n_in))
encoder_inputs = Masking(mask_value=0)(encoder_inputs) #****** TEST *****
encoder = LSTM(n_units, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_inputs)
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]
# define decoder
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, n_out))
decoder_inputs = Masking(mask_value=0)(decoder_inputs) #****** TEST *****
decoder_lstm = LSTM(n_units, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = Dense(n_out, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
# define inference encoder
encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)
# define inference decoder
decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape=(n_units,))
decoder_state_input_c = Input(shape=(n_units,))
decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]
decoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)
decoder_states = [state_h, state_c]
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
decoder_model = Model([decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs, [decoder_outputs] + decoder_states)
# return all models
return model, encoder_model, decoder_model
```

Any idea how to tweak this so the new Masking functions work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pay attention when you define layers in order to not override them especially the inputs

```
def define_models(n_in, n_out, n_units):

    # define encoder
    enc_inputs = Input(shape=(None, n_in))
    encoder_inputs = Masking(mask_value=0)(enc_inputs) #****** TEST *****
    encoder = LSTM(n_units, return_state=True)
    encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_inputs)
    encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

    # define decoder
    dec_inputs = Input(shape=(None, n_out))
    decoder_inputs = Masking(mask_value=0)(dec_inputs) #****** TEST *****
    decoder_lstm = LSTM(n_units, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
    decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs, initial_state=encoder_states)
    decoder_dense = Dense(n_out, activation='softmax')
    decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
    model = Model([enc_inputs, dec_inputs], decoder_outputs)

    # define inference encoder
    encoder_model = Model(enc_inputs, encoder_states)

    # define inference decoder
    decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape=(n_units,))
    decoder_state_input_c = Input(shape=(n_units,))
    decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]
    decoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)
    decoder_states = [state_h, state_c]
    decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
    decoder_model = Model([dec_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs, [decoder_outputs] + decoder_states)

    # return all models
    return model, encoder_model, decoder_model
```